# Error opening emulator when running a AVD

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, virtual-machine

I have created an AVD in android studio and apparently I was experiencing an error that "the device has terminated". After searching on internet, I was guided on how to apply SDK in project structure which I have done, but then when I try running that device again I get an error that

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) 
          (CL:N/A) 
INFO    | Found systemPath 
          C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\ 
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file 
C:\Users\Smart\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading. 
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: 
          C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu 
          crash.db, detection is enabled 
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each 
          indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. 
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.1 
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: 
https://clients2.google.com/cr/report INFO | Report 3272f61c-674d-4b1a-b7bc-3fd53534a3c1 is available remotely as: d49d5761a970dbec, deleting. INFO    | added library C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll 
INFO    | Sending adb public key 
[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 @unknown] 
          HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
WARNING | *** Basic token auth will be deprecated 
          soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt *** 
INFO    | Started GRPC 
          server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token 
INFO    | Advertising in: 
          C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_1676.ini 
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1440x2560, dpi: 560x560"
```

What am I not doing right

I have tried searching on internet and implemented all the suggestions but I can't get it through